# Merging / aggregating multiple documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a little problem with my aggregations. I have a large collection of flat documents with the following schema:

```
{
  _id:ObjectId("5dc027d38da295b969eca568"),
  emp_no:10001,
  salary:60117,
  from_date:"1986-06-26",
  to_date:"1987-06-26"
}
```

It's all about annual employee salaries. The data is exported from relational database so there are multiple documents with the same value of *"emp_no"* but the rest of their attributes vary. I need to aggregate them by values of attribute "emp_no" so as a result I will have something like this:

```
//one document
{
  _id:ObjectId("5dc027d38da295b969eca568"),
  emp_no:10001,
  salaries: [
    {
      salary:60117,
      from_date:"1986-06-26",
      to_date:"1987-06-26"
    },
    {
      salary:62102,
      from_date:"1987-06-26",
      to_date:"1988-06-25"
    },
    ...
  ]
}

//another document
{
  _id:ObjectId("5dc027d38da295b969eca579"),
  emp_no:10002,
  salaries: [
    {
      salary:65828,
      from_date:"1996-08-03",
      to_date:"1997-08-03"
    },
    ...
  ]
}

//and so on
```

Last but not least there are almost 2.9m of documents so aggregating by *"emp_no"* manually would be a bit of a problem. 
 Is there a way I can aggregate them using just mongo queries? How do I do this kind of thing? Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group stage of aggregation pipeline can be used to get this type of aggregates. Specify the attribute you want to group by as the value of `_id` field in the group stage.

How does the below query work for you?

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$emp_no",
      "salaries": {
        "$push": {
          "salary": "$salary",
          "from_data": "$from_date",
          "to_data": "$to_date"
        }
      },
      "emp_no": {
        "$first": "$emp_no"
      },
      "first_document_id": {
        "$first": "$_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": "$first_document_id",
      "salaries": 1,
      "emp_no": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: It works :) but what about keeping _id as one of ObjectId's like before and emp_no as emp_no?

Comment: Right, it is possible to keep _id as one of the ObjectIds and emp_no as is. I edited the query in my answer.

Comment: Pleased to be of help to you :)